# How to use Workbox Background Sync in an Web App for offline post requests

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am trying to create an webapp which supports offline post requests.I used workbox to precache my files but the plugin Background Sync doesnt work.I didnt see the queued requests in IndexedDB with Chrome Dev Tools. How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Service Worker file:

```js
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.2.0/workbox-sw.js');

//The new installed service worker replaces the old service worker immediately
self.skipWaiting();

//Test workbox
if (workbox) {
    console.log('Workbox is loaded');
} else {
    console.log('Workbox did not loaded');
}


//Precaching
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
    { url: 'index.html', revision: '0000' },
    { url: 'manifest.json', revision: '0000' },
    { url: 'images/icons/icon-48x48.png', revision: '0000' },
]);

//BackgroundSync
//On https://ptsv2.com/t/n5y9f-1556037444 you can check for received posts
const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('queue', {
    maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    'https://ptsv2.com/t/n5y9f-1556037444/post',
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
        plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
    }),
    'POST'
);
```

In index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!--Include Manifest (Metadata for Browser)-->
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <!--Metadata for Apple-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Weather PWA">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icons/icon-144x144.png">
    <!--Metadata for Microsoft-->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/icons/icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2F3BA2">
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="sendPost()">Send post</button>

    <!--Register Service Worker-->
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker
                .register('service-worker.js')
                .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
        }
    </script>

    <!--Send the post request-->
    <script>
        function sendPost() {
            console.log("Send post...");
            fetch('https://ptsv2.com/t/n5y9f-1556037444/post', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                mode:'no-cors',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'hello world'
                }),
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log('Sended data', res);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error while sending data', error);
            })

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```